# Query local time

Tags: django, postgresql, timezone

For a shop, I would like store opening and closing times in local time for that given shop. Example:

Shop1 opens at 8.00 (t1), and closes at 16.00 (t2) local time. Shop1 is located in Europe/London (tz).

Shop2 opens at 8.00 and closes at 16.00 local time. Shop2 is located in Europe/Copenhagen.

**The question**: How do I at a given time select shops that are open? I need to take into account DST: In this example in the summer, Shop1 open time will be 08:00+01:00, Shop2 open time will be 08:00+02:00 while in the winter, this will be 08:00+00:00 for Shop1 and 08:00+01:00 for Shop2.

Will be selecting from a table with many rows, hence I need this to be indexed.

Using Django + PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres supports converting a time to a local time using the `at time zone` syntax.  For example to find the current time in New Zealand:

```
select (current_timestamp at time zone 'NZDT')::time;
```

You could use this to select shops that are open at 10:00:

```
where   ('10:00'::time at time zone time_zone)::time
        between opens and closes
```

Where `time_zone` is the timezone for the shop, `opens` the time it opens, and `closes` the time it closes.  [Full example at regtester.com.](http://rextester.com/BRQ43610)

Comment: That's very cool. I was trying something out ala this but could not figure out how to make this work. Any insights into the costs of the local time calculation? Which indexes would I need to add to make this execute fast for ~1 million rows?

Answer (score 1):

Cool question.  Continuing [Andomar's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42231899/57952), assuming you are handling a few timezones with "unexpected" daylight saving date ranges, one option would would be:

- Save the timezone in a `CharField`, and `opens` and `closes` in a `TimeField`:

  ```
  class Shop(models.Model):
      tz = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      opens = models.TimeField()
      closes = models.TimeField()

  Shop.objects.create(opens="8:00", closes="19:00", tz="Europe/Moscow")
  Shop.objects.create(opens="8:00", closes="19:00", tz="Europe/Berlin")
  Shop.objects.create(opens="8:00", closes="19:00", tz="UTC")
  Shop.objects.create(opens="8:00", closes="19:00", tz="Asia/Jerusalem")
  Shop.objects.create(opens="8:00", closes="19:00", tz="Europe/London")
  Shop.objects.create(opens="8:00", closes="19:00", tz="Europe/Copenhagen")
  ```
- Calculate "now" as UTC:

  ```
  now_utc = "10:30"
  ```
- Annotate and filter your queryset with RawSQL:

  ```
  qs = Shop.objects.annotate(is_open=RawSQL("(%s::time at time zone tz)::time between opens and closes", (now_utc,))).filter(is_open=True)
  ```

Another solution would be to query the db for each timezone:

```
# pseudocode
for tz in all_timezones:
    now_local = convert_to_timezone(now, tz) # beware - this might fail when DST is currently changing!
    shops = Shop.objects.filter(tz=tz, opens__lte=now_local, closes__gte=now_local)
```

If you `index_together` fields (`tz`, `opens`, `closes`), the query should utilize the index.  However, this does not mean your query will be faster.

Keep in mind you will have to keep your opening hours that surrounds midnight in two records "22:00"-"00:00" and "00:00"-"03:00" instead of "22:00"-"03:00".